# How to implement Brute force techniques in Keycloak authenticator

Tags: redhat, keycloak, brute-force, keycloak-services

I am created separate authenticator for Login page with some custom validation. With that, I want to implement the Keycloak Brute force technique. I got some reference from `DefaultBruteForceProtector.class`. If I use that class I am getting the below error 
`Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/services/managers/DefaultBruteForceProtector` can anyone suggest any other option to implement the brute force technique.

Comment: what have you tried? - can you add some information on what you have done before getting this exception?

Comment: I have tried to invoke the thread from the `DefaultBruteForceProtector.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class loading in Wildfly is restrictive for security reasons.
You've to specify explicitly the dependencies of your custom authenticator by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the META-INF of this jar.

Here is a typical jboss-deployment-structure.xml , we use in our custom authenticator :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core" />
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Hope this will help.

Regards,